# ace:chart set fraction values for axes

Tags: jsf, charts, icefaces

I am using IceFaces, ace:chart to display chart in my application.On my y-axes, I have values in fractions (61.3, 62.1 etc).  But, when graph is rendered values are rounded off to whole number (61,63 etc)

Is is possible to display values in fractions ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer finally !!! we have to put setFormatString while setting y axes.

```
private Axis[] yAxes = new Axis[] {
            new Axis() {{               
                setLabel("Power level (dBuV)");
                setFormatString("%.1f");
            }}
    };
```

[image]